# consequences of committing large amount of binary files in git repository

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have just performed a merge in git.
Unfortunately, due to differences in .gitignore settings between branches, a large number of large binary files has been committed and pushed after the merge.

Later, I have removed the files from the folder, committed their delete, added them to .gitignore and copied them back to the folder.

This way I restored the pre-merge situation.
However, the large files created a huge commit (GBs) with super lenghty diff which also shadows the actual merge commits.

Beside polluting the history, is there any other negative consequence of such a dumb action (computationally is this gonna slow down anything)?
How to cleanup this mess in terms of disk resources and clarity of the git logs?

Comment: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: thanks, this is already quite a relief :) but what are the reasons why I should be using such a tool?

Comment: Try doing a fresh Git clone now, and you will see ;)

Comment: ah f*ck, so now the footprint of a new clone is several GBs?

Comment: Indeed.  The large object is still present + reachable in your repo history.

Comment: but only for a new clone if I am not mistaken, not just a new fetch?so I have time until Monday to save my job :) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160817/discussion-between-errorisalvo-and-oliver-charlesworth).

Comment: @ErroriSalvo Does the binary files only exist in the merged commit or serial  commits in a branch?

Comment: only in the merged commit. before, they were .gitignored in the branch

Comment: Example of a consequence on a project: libigl had its history rewritten to remove the commits introducing binary files: https://libigl.github.io/rewritten-history/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the consequences: the biggest impact would be on clone operations - which, of course, could be slow due to transferring the large amount of data.  In some circumstances fetch or push could also be affected.  I wouldn't expect much impact on other git operations.  Most things are done locally and hashes are used where possible, so only when the content of one of the large files is actually relevant to an operation would that operation be directly affected by the size of the file.

(I suppose depending on underlying file system, operations on pack files containing the large objects could *theoretically* be affected, but that sounds like a stretch to me.)

The easiest way to clean up the history is with the BFG Repo Cleaner.  Doing so constitutes a history rewrite, so all the usual caveats about coordinating with other repo users would apply.

Comment: so basically, if someone fetches during the next few days while I fix it, will they download to their local filesystems tons of garbage objects?

Comment: of course the files are now not in master anymore, so even if they pull any other commit that the wrong one, they should not be downloaded

Comment: If you keep the object in your history, then even after you've "fixed" current commits they will still be downloaded by default.  Clones are complete copies of the repo; that's how it's possible for almost all operations to be done locally.  The fact that they may not see the files in their working tree doesn't mean that the files aren't copied (in pack files) to their computer.